# sqlite odbc silent install

Tags: sqlite

How to Silent install sqlite odbc driver ?. Found here http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

i found 2 methods to connect to sqlite one is above and the other one is dhSqlite(vbRichclient4.dll,vb_cairo_sqlite.dll and DirectCOM.dll). which is a class library and replacement for ADO it seems for sqlite. but i could not find any documentation for this one.

i like sqliteodbc because it just works with ADO. but dhsqlite can be installed along with the app. Also dhSqlite contains the sqlite3 engine also i suppose. is it true?.

Could you suggest which one i could follow? or is there any other option i could check?. I am looking for it to be a silent install or install as 
part of my app. itself; free and supported for vb6

Thanks

Comment: hello anybody please??

Answer (score 2):

If you use Inno Setup for distributing your application and use sqliteodbc 0.9996 version, we can add script like this:

**[Files]**

Source: sqliteodbc0.9996.exe; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall

**[Run]**

Filename: {tmp}\sqliteodbc0.9996.exe; Parameters: /S; StatusMsg: "Installing SQLite ODBC Connector..."

Answer (score 0):

Win32 install/remove/shell by RUNDLL32

Each driver DLL provides entry points for ODBC driver installation
  and removal which can be invoked from RUNDLL32.EXE, eg

### install sqliteodbc.dll
  C:> rundll32 [path]sqliteodbc.dll,install [quiet]

### remove sqlite3odbc.dll
  C:> rundll32 [path]sqlite3odbc.dll,uninstall [quiet]